# Aws sam local start-api with binary support

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I try to test a lambda function with a binary result (gzip stream).

I would like to use `sam local start-api` to test my API.
This API return a binary result like this:

```
response.body = base64.b64encode("hello".encode('utf-8'))
#response.headers["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip"
response["isBase64Encoded"] = True
return response
```

The result see by the browser is base64 encoded (`aGVsbG8=`), and not a binary result (`hello`).

It's possible to activate the [binary support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings-configure-with-console.html) in AWS console, but how it's possible to activate the binary support `with sam local start-api` ?